# auto extend tr for example 100px

Tags: html, css

i have:

```
<table border="2">
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>                
         <td> 2 </td> 
         <td> 2 </td>
         <td> 2 </td>
         <td> 2 </td> 
         <td> 2 </td> 
         <td> 2 </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

this generate:

```
|1|1|1|1|
|2|2|2|2|2|2|
```

how can i make something:

```
| 1 | 1| 1|1|
|2|2|2|2|2|2|
```

i dont will merge td with 1. I would like set constant width for example 100px; and < tr> same was extended.

Comment: have you considered using colspan? http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a colspan. Its easy to maintain, and you don't need any JS or CSS workaround.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html

or as tutorial:

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html

if you want custom width, you gonna need classes if you care about old browsers, or targeting them with CSS3

Comment: if i use colspan must i same this set. i would like auto width

Comment: the with is auto, it takes the width of to cols no matter how large they are or do i understand something wrong? Maybe you need to be a little more precise in your question.